# Como usar o StitchAppClientConfiguration do mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk no Javascript do navegador?

Tags: javascript, api, mongodb, navegador-de-internet, cross-browser

Eu tentei usar o código para informar localAppNamelocal e localAppVersion em JavaScript, mas não encontro nenhum exemplo claro na web. Alguém com conhecimento sobre Stitch pode nos mostrar o correto?

```
import {
    Stitch as Stitch,
    StitchAppClientConfiguration as StitchAppClientConfiguration
} from "mongodb-stitch-browser-sdk";

var ClientConfiguration = new StitchAppClientConfiguration.Builder().build()

ClientConfiguration.localAppName = 'My App'
ClientConfiguration.localAppVersion = '0.1'

Stitch.initializeDefaultAppClient('myapp-cast', ClientConfiguration)
```

Tentei encontrar, mas não achei nada, nenhum um exemplo claro na web ou na documentação.

**Gratidão** por qualquer ajuda!

Comment: Existem as [entradas na documentação](https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch-sdks/js/4/classes/stitchappclientconfiguration.builder.html#withlocalappname) associadas aos respectivos fontes. Veja se ajuda

Comment: Com base na documentação eu cheguei ao código acima, testei e tive como retorno o Objeto abaixo no painel do **Atlas Stitch** apareceu a versão correta no controle de conexões de aplicativos clientes: 
 
  `"StitchAppClientConfiguration"{
   "baseUrl":"undefined",
   "storage":"undefined",
   "dataDirectory":"undefined",
   "transport":"undefined",
   "localAppName":"My App",
   "localAppVersion":"0.1"
}`